# How to properly catch and handle errors from .net8 with React

Tags: reactjs, jsx, .net-8.0

what is the best way to handle errors with React when your backend is built in .net8? I am starting to wonder if my backend is handling errors correctly or I'm not writing correct react code. on my RegisterModel I have the [Required] Annotation as well. Any resources I can read will also help, I really need to learn this.

A few of my issues are:

1. instead of getting just the error that triggered the email validation, I get both
2. when I try to register the same user I won't get user already exist.

Register.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Input from '../UI/Input';
import Select from '../UI/Select';
import classes from '../Components/Register.module.css'
import Button from '../UI/Button';

const Register = () => {

  // State to hold form data
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    UserName: '',
    FirstName: '',
    LastName: '',
    Password: '',
    Email: '',
    Gender: '',
    Church: '',
  });

  // State to display errors
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})

  // State to hold church data
  const [churchData, setChurchData] = useState({
    Church: '',
  });

  const [result, setResult] = useState(null)


  // Fetch church names from the API when the component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchChurchNames = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5180/api/church/allChurches');

        // Check if response.data.$values is an array
        if (Array.isArray(response.data.$values)) {
          setChurchData({ Church: response.data.$values });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching church names:', error);
      }
    };
    fetchChurchNames();
  }, []);

  // Handle form input changes
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setFormData((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    // Prevent the default form submission behavior
    event.preventDefault();
  
    try {

      // Create a copy of the form data and convert the Church field to a number if it's not an empty string
      const dataToSend = { ...formData, Church: formData.Church === '' ? null : +formData.Church };
  
      // Send a POST request to the registration API endpoint with the adjusted data
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:5180/api/account/register', dataToSend);
  
      // Log a success message and the API response data when registration is successful
      console.log('Registration successful:', response.data);
      setResult({
        status: 'Success',
        message: 'User registered successfully!',
      });

      // Clear the form data after successful registration
      setFormData({
        username: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: '',
        gender: '',
        Church: '', 
      });

    } catch (error) {
      // Check if the server responded with a 400 status (validation error)
      if (error.response.status === 400) {
        // Log validation errors to the console for debugging
        console.log('Validation errors:', error.response.data.errors);
        setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
        setResult({
          status: 'Error',
          message: 'User registration failed. Please check the form for errors.',
        });
      } else {
        // Log other errors (server errors) to the console
        console.error('Registration Failed:', error.response.data);
        setResult({
          status: 'Error',
          message: 'An unexpected error occurred during registration. Please try again later.',
        });
      }
    }
  };

  // Render the registration form
  return (
    <div className='wrapper'>
      <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className={classes.heading}>
          <h2 className={classes.heading}>Registration</h2>
          <p className={classes.signIn}>Already have an account <a href='login'>Sign In </a></p>
        </div>

        {result && (
        <div className={result.status === 'Success' ? 'success' : 'error'}>
          {result.message}        
          </div>
      )};

        {/* Render input fields */}
        <div className={classes.formGroup}>
          <Input label='UserName' id='username' type='text' name='UserName' onChange={handleChange} error={errors && errors.Username } />

          <Input label='FirstName' id='firstname' type='text' name='FirstName' onChange={handleChange} error={errors && errors.FirstName }  />
          <Input label='LastName' id='lastname' type='text' name='LastName' onChange={handleChange}error={errors && errors.LastName }  />
        </div>

        <Input label='Email' id='Email' type='email' name='Email' onChange={handleChange}error={errors && errors.Email && errors.Email.length > 0 ? errors.Email : null}
/>
        <Input label='Gender' id='gender' type='text' name='Gender' onChange={handleChange}error={errors && errors.Gender}  />

        {/* Render church dropdown */}
        <Select
          label='Church'
          name='Church'
          value={formData.Church}
          options={churchData.Church || []} // Ensure that options is an array
          error={errors && errors.Church}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />

        <Input label='Password' id='password' type='password' name='Password' onChange={handleChange}error={errors && errors.Password }  />
        <Input label='Confirm Password' id='ConfirmPassword' type='password' name='ConfirmPassword' onChange={handleChange}error={errors && errors.ConfirmPassword }  />

        {/* Render form action buttons */}
        <p className={classes.formActions}>
          {/* <button className="button button-flat">Reset</button> */}
          <Button className={classes.button}>Register</Button>
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
//TODO: I need to set up reset form button.
//* IMPORTANT: WORKING ON GETTING THE EMAIL TO BE VALIDATED AND ERRORS SHOW BASED ON USER INVALID INPUTS.
```

AccountController.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterModel register)
    {
        try
        {
            // Validate incoming request
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Check if the email already exists
                var userExist = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(register.Email);

                if (userExist != null)
                {
                    return BadRequest("User already exist.");
                }

                // Check if the password and confirm password match
                if (register.Password != register.ConfirmPassword)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Passwords must match");
                }

                // Create user
                var newUser = new User
                {
                    UserName = register.Username,
                    FirstName = register.FirstName,
                    LastName = register.LastName,
                    Email = register.Email,
                    Gender = register.Gender,
                    ChurchId = register.Church
                };

                var creationResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, register.Password);

                if (creationResult.Succeeded)
                {

                    return Ok(new AuthResult
                    {
                        Status = "Success",
                        Message = "User created successfully!"
                    });
                }

                // Log the details of the failure
                _logger.LogError($"User registration failed: {string.Join(", ", creationResult.Errors)}");

                return BadRequest(new AuthResult
                {
                    Errors = creationResult.Errors.Select(error => error.Description).ToList(),
                    Status = "Failed"
                });
            }
            else
            {
                // ModelState is invalid, return detailed validation errors
                return BadRequest(new AuthResult
                {
                    Errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)).ToList(),
                    Status = "Failed"
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log unexpected exceptions
            _logger.LogError($"An unexpected error occurred during user registration: {ex}");
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "An unexpected error occurred.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do some sort of alert for error messages so user knows what's wrong.
Other than that you can make handling requests and its response generic like this:

```
const baseURL = 'http://localhost:5180/api/';
const httpClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:5180/api/'
});
const handleApiResponse = function (httpResponse) {
  if (httpResponse.status >= 200 && httpResponse.status < 300) {
    return {
      isSuccess: true,
      isError: false,
      isValidationError: false,
      data: httpResponse.data,
      error: null,
      validationErrors: null
    }
  }
}


const handleExceptionApiResponse = function (axiosError) {
  if (axiosError.response && axiosError.response.status === 400) {
    return {
      statusCode: axiosError.response.status,
      isSuccess: false,
      isError: false,
      isValidationError: true,
      data: null,
      error: axiosError.request.response,
      validationErrors: axiosError.response.data.errors
    }
  }
  else if (axiosError.response ) {
    return {
      statusCode: axiosError.response.status,
      isSuccess: false,
      isError: true,
      isValidationError: false,
      data: null,
      error: "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
      validationErrors: null
    }
  }
}

const api = (axios) => {
  const baseUrl = baseURL;
  return {
    getPhotoUrl: (photoId, config = {}) => {
      return baseURL + "/Photos/" + photoId;
    },
    getById: async (url, config = {}) => {
      try {
        var response = await axios.get(baseUrl + url, config);
        return handleApiResponse(response);
      } catch (e) {
        return handleExceptionApiResponse(e);
      }
    },
    get: async (url, config = {}) => {
      try {
        var response = await axios.get(baseUrl + url, config);
        return handleApiResponse(response);
      } catch (e) {
        return handleExceptionApiResponse(e);
      }
    },
    delete: async (url, config = {}) => {
      try {
        var response = await axios.delete(baseUrl + url, config);
        return handleApiResponse(response);
      } catch (e) {
        return handleExceptionApiResponse(e);
      }
    },
    put: async (url, body, config = {}) => {
      try {
        var response = await axios.put(baseUrl + url, body, config);
        return handleApiResponse(response);
      } catch (e) {
        return handleExceptionApiResponse(e);
      }
    },
    post: async (url, body, config = {}) => {
      try {
        var response = await axios.post(baseUrl + url, body, config);
        return handleApiResponse(response);
      } catch (e) {
        return handleExceptionApiResponse(e);
      }
    },
  };
};

export const httpSmartClient = api(httpClient);
export default httpClient;
```

Now you create service for everything you need so you dont repeat your code:

```
import { httpSmartClient } from "..";

const baseName = "accounts";

const AccountsService = {
  register: async (data) => {
    var response = await httpSmartClient.post(`/${baseName}/register` + data);
    return response;
  }

export default AccountsService;
```

After that you are all set up with minimal repeating code and handling response/errors.
You do api call like this now:

```
let response = await AccountsService.register(data);
```

For backend you can create custom exceptions for an example UserExistsException, then you do this to throw errors and catch them:

```
try{
 if(usersExists)
   throw new UserExistsException();
}
catch(UserExistsException ex){
_logger.LogError($"User already exists: {ex}");
return StatusCode(409,"User already exists");
}
catch(Exception ex){
 _logger.LogError($"An unexpected error occurred during user registration: {ex}");
return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "An unexpected error occurred.");
}
```

Note that your custom UserExistsException has to inherit class : Exception.
One more tip: look into React Hook Froms, it will make your life easier !
Hope it helps or at least gives you insights !

Comment: Thank you I will dive deeper into this. i know i will have further questions later but let me see what i understand first.

Comment: Just ask if you have, have fun :)

Comment: ok everything is going pretty well. except I keep getting a 500(internal Server Error) I know what the message is, User already exist, seen it on the Network tab in console. but the frontend is not able to catch it to display it properly for the user to know.

Comment: You should check console.log(response.statusCode), and based on statusCode you have to render error message conditionally, if it's 409 it means user exists and change state which will show error message

Comment: So I tried building out the login route because somethings with the error handling from the server is weired and i dont understand. but what i found out is no matter what my response comes back null. everytime i console.log it, but if i was to add proper credentials everything works fine.

Comment: I dont think you implemented logic  i showed you up there correctely then.. Go through it once again